# Winston js log files inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, logging, docker-volume, winston

I am trying to use winston to write the logs of my node js app inside a file named `logs.log` which is on my local c:// . Now I'm dockerizing my app in order to deploy it into the production cluster and I have some questions concerning where to set the path for the logs files on the container and how to be able to visualize them.

I'm thinking of creating a `/app/logs/logs.log` file within my dockerfile using `RUN mkdir` and set this path in my logger.js but I am not sure whether this is enough or should there be any other configurations to set like the volume mount etc.

Comment: Depends. If you want your logs to be persistent and to be readable even when the container has been killed/removed, you'll probably have to go with the volume mounts, indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I'm still new to this I'm having problems configuring this volume mount when using helm charts. Do you have a link in mind that could help?

Comment: Since you talk about "production **cluster**" and "helm charts", I assume you talk about a K8s cluster. In this case, [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) __might__ help you.

Comment: In Docker (and especially in Kubernetes) it's much easier to manage logs written to containers' stdout than to try to manage file-based logs.  Can you use a Winston console logger instead, and review them with `docker logs` (or `kubectl logs`)?